# How to select entries based on index returned by tf.argmin in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given two matrices of the same shape `Loss` and `Weights`.
I need to return the result of `tf.reduce_min(Loss, axis=0)` and also the corresponding weights from the `Weights` matrix (selected from the same indices where `tf.reduce_min` selected its results).

I can use `tf.argmin(Loss, 0)` to find the indices with the minimal values. How do I use these indices to get the corresponding values from the `Weights` matrix? I think is possible to implement using `tf.gather`, but the results won't be differentiable. Any known solutions to this?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [softmin](https://pdollar.github.io/toolbox/classify/softMin.html) on the `Loss` followed by a `tf.matmul(..., Weights)` to get (an approximation to) the corresponding values? That should be differentiable all the way through, although it will involve more computation than `tf.argmin()` and `tf.gather()`.

Answer (score 0):

Gather is differentiable, on the values it returns. It wont be differentiable w.r.t. the indices, because that is mathematically impossible.